# Prevent Mapstruct from using a method in automatic mapper detection

Tags: mapstruct

I have a Mapstruct mapper where I must do some String conversion service. Namely, from a list of natural-language phrases to an opaque constant defined in a utility class. No, I won't be using enums this time. It involves some Levenshtein check with a list of predefined wordings.

I have a method `String getSyntheticDescription(String description)` in a Spring bean that I want to use to map a **single** String field in my DTO.

If i use Mapstruct's `uses` attribute in `@Mapping`, I have found Mapstruct will abuse `definedBean.getSyntheticDescription` all around String conversions. Basically every String field mapping to a String is passed to `definedBean.getSyntheticDescription`, which is obviously not what I want.

I want to use that in an `expression` attribute for a single field only.

How do I tell Mapstruct not to try to use all available methods for mapping and specifically ignore `getSyntheticDescription` unless instructed otherwise?

Code

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {TaxonomyStringParser.class, TaxonomyCustomerLogic.class})
public interface TaxonomyControlMapping {

    @Mapping(target = "notcompliant", source = "nonConforme")
    @Mapping(target = "withurgency", source = "nonConformeConCriticita")
    @Mapping(target = "compliant", source = "conforme")
    @Mapping(target = "perimeter", expression = "java(taxonomyCustomerLogic.getControlPerimeterValueFromDescription(dto.getPerimetroAnalisi()))")
    @Mapping(target = "sampling", source = "campionamento")
    @Mapping(target = "performer", source = "performer")
    TaxonomyControlVersion fromMasterDbDto(TaxonomyControlMasterDbDTO dto) throws ParseException;


}
```

Results in

```java
        taxonomyControlVersion.setInstructions( taxonomyCustomerLogic.getControlPerimeterValueFromDescription( dto.getIndicazioniValutazione() ) );
        taxonomyControlVersion.setSignificance( taxonomyCustomerLogic.getControlPerimeterValueFromDescription( dto.getSignificativita() ) ); //BAD
        taxonomyControlVersion.setSamplingmode( taxonomyStringParser.parseSamplingModeType( dto.getModalitaCampionamento() ) ); //BAD

        taxonomyControlVersion.setPerimeter( taxonomyCustomerLogic.getControlPerimeterValueFromDescription(dto.getPerimetroAnalisi()) ); //GOOD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for a method to only be used in a specific use case it needs to be annotated with `@Named` from `org.mapstruct` or a custom `@Qualifier` also from `org.mapstruct`.

In your case you can add `@Named("syntheticDescription")` to your method in the Spring bean and then use `Mapping#qualifiedByName`.

e.g.

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {TaxonomyStringParser.class, TaxonomyCustomerLogic.class})
public interface TaxonomyControlMapping {

    @Mapping(target = "notcompliant", source = "nonConforme")
    @Mapping(target = "withurgency", source = "nonConformeConCriticita")
    @Mapping(target = "compliant", source = "conforme")
    @Mapping(target = "perimeter", source = "perimetroAnalisi" qualifiedByName = "syntheticDescription" )
    @Mapping(target = "sampling", source = "campionamento")
    @Mapping(target = "performer", source = "performer")
    TaxonomyControlVersion fromMasterDbDto(TaxonomyControlMasterDbDTO dto) throws ParseException;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem injecting the bean via setter and deleting it from the Mapper(use) attribute

Example:

```
@Mapper(
    config = CentralConfig.class
    //do not write here uses = Service.class
)
public abstract class AccountMapper {

    protected Service service;
    @Autowired
    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Then mapper uses only one method I asked him with @Mapping(expression)